# find command is able to find the directories but find with -exec rm -r is not able to delete

Tags: shell, unix, find

i am running this find command

```
find . -mindepth 3 -name [1-9]* -type d
```

and its returning a set of results 
like

```
./B*********/*/output/simulation/9
./B********/*/output/simulation/8
./B********/*/output/simulation/7
./B********/*/output/simulation/5
./B********/*/output/simulation/6
./B********/*/output/simulation/4
```

now when I am running

```
find . -mindepth 3 -name [1-9]* -type d -exec rm -r {} \;
```

on the same directory

```
find :./B*********/*/output/simulation/9  No such file or directory
find :./B********/*/output/simulation/8    No such file or directory
find :./B********/*/output/simulation/7    No such file or directory
find :./B********/*/output/simulation/5    No such file or directory
find :./B********/*/output/simulation/6    No such file or directory
find :./B********/*/output/simulation/4    No such file or directory
```

any idea what is going wrong

P.S I have used * to hide the file name for sake of confidentiality

Comment: You want `[1-9]*` to be processed by [tag:find], not the shell, so you need to quote it, otherwise you may get inaccurate output, `find . -mindepth 3 -name '[1-9]*' -type d -exec rm -r {} \;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this find with quotes around `{}`:

```
find . -mindepth 3 -name [1-9]* -type d -exec rm -rf '{}' \;
```

Comment: Are there any shell settings that actually cause this to be an issue?  Also, probably worth removing the `-f` in your command, just so OP doesn't accidentally execute it and get promptless `rm`.

Comment: `rm -r {}` will also not prompt the user, if that is what OP wants then he/she will need `rm -ir '{}'`